# GCM Push notification not working when App is no longer running

Tags: android, service, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing GCM push notification service, for that I used **Service** class to extend my class. So Service that I implemented is running in background continuously. But I am not getting any notification when app is ***idle for long time***.It is working only for, when app is running in stack.

I know, we cannot get notification when App is close from Stack.

Please help me to get notification when app is not running for long time (like Whatsapp or Gmail).

I used **IntentService** but it is working only when app is running(foreground or background).

Comment: have you found any solution or not ??

Comment: Can you please tell me what you did ??

Comment: Used 'Service' class and override 'onStartCommand' method.

Comment: I am using GcmListenerService and it does not have any 'onStartCommand' method to override ??

Comment: @Sudhanshu used like.. public class yourclassname extends Service {}

Comment: SO without using GcmListenerService how are you doing this ?? can you please show me your whole code

Comment: @RoHiT, could you post the solution you found as an answer under this question. This would help a lot!

Comment: public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends Service {}

Answer (score 1):

Read this, [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) stops itself when it runs out of work.

and about notification it may be comes at any time for that you need to put BroadcastReceiver.

Create service class by **extends Service** : [Tutorial about Service](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly you are doing and what your code is. I would recommend you download Google's GCM sample here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Get that to work first (just use your server to push the push to the app).

Then you can just implement that boiler plate code in your own app and it should work as expected.

Hope that helps.